# Change the background color of the toast message Ionic 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic4

How can I change the background color of the toast message?

I have tried this: But no luck. Is that due to the `shadow DOM` effect?

*variable.scss*

```
--background:red;
```

*global.scss*

```
ion-toast>.toast-wrapper {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

*.ts*

```
  async showErrorToast(data: string) {
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: data,
      duration: 3000000,
      position: 'bottom'
    });
    toast.present();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: what if you try only this `.toast-wrapper {
    background-color: red !important;
}`

Comment: I have tried that. But it has never been applied. Is that because of `Shadow DOM`? @TemaniAfif

Comment: yes it's because of the shadow, I noticed this .. the CSS should be added inside

Comment: How can I hack this? @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the color in the toast parameters:

```
 const toastController = document.querySelector('ion-toast-controller');
 await toastController.componentOnReady();
 const toast = await toastController.create({
   showCloseButton: false,
   message: 'test toast message',
   position: 'top',
   duration: 2000,
   color: 'danger'
 });
 await toast.present();
```

Answer (score 1):

first define class like this :

```
.toast-bg {
background-color:red;
}
```

then pass class as param to toast option like this :

```
{
    message: data,
    duration: 3000000,
    position: 'bottom',
    cssClass:'toast-bg'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure youe declare the sytle class in the public .scss file. I think it is called `app.scss` for Ionic 3 and `global.scss` in Ionic v4.

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking for a solution with Ionic v7, this is what you can do to apply custom CSS for toastController.

1. Specify `cssClass` property in `toastController.create()`.

   ```
   const toast = await this.toastController.create({
     message: 'Your Toast Message',
     duration: 2000,
     cssClass: 'toast-success'
   });
   ```
2. In your `global.scss`, specify your styles.

   ```
   ion-toast.toast-success {
     &::part(container) {
       background: #24a148;
       color: #fff;
       border-color: #24a148;
       border-radius: 4px;
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `cssClass` property while creating the toast and add the class name to it

```
 async showErrorToast(data: string) {
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: data,
      duration: 3000000,
      position: 'bottom',
      cssClass: 'toast_style'
    });
    toast.present();
  }
```

Add style class

```
.toast_style {
background-color:red;
}
```

Refer ionic documentation of toast here [toast](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast)

Answer (score 0):

You can use colors from your application's color palette. Default options are: `primary`, `secondary`, `tertiary`, `success`, `warning`, `danger`, `light`, `medium`, and `dark`.

```
async showErrorToast(data: string) {
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      ...
      color: 'primary'
    });
    toast.present();
  }
```

for more details [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast)

Answer (score 0):

this solution works in ionic v4 as well as in ionic v6:

first define your background color using the ionic attribute "--background" (class does not need to be defined in global.scss)

```
.toast-background {
    --background: rgb(175,175,175);
}
```

and then reference the new class when you launch your toastController

```
const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Message Here.',
    duration: 30000,
    cssClass: 'toast-background'
});
toast.present();
```